# Jquery icon button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Hey I'm trying to make an icon button that collapses and expands some text. I already have working logic for the collapse/expand part but where I'm finding trouble is creating the icon button. I have to use a downloaded theme so what I have is:

```
<span id="toggleErrorBtn" class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus" style="background-image: url(images/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png); height: 15px; border:white; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: inline;">
    <button></button>
</span>
```

When I run my code I see the icon next to an empty button but when I try to use "display:none;" on the button, everything disappears. Is there a way to remove the button and leave the icon?

EDIT: The image is for a different color. I tried changing the button to visibility: hidden; but it left me with two icons, but replacing the button with `&nbsp;` worked nice. The only problem now is that when the mouse hovers over the icon it identifies it as text instead of a button. Ideally I'd like

```
<button id="toggleErrorBtn" class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus" style="background-image: url(images/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png); height: 15px; border:white; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: inline; background-position-x: -20px;">
    </button>
```

but then I can't change the background color. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: If you put nothing within a `span` it will collapse and dissapear from the DOM. You can put a non-breaking space, `&nbsp;`, into the span to keep it from collapsing when you remove the button.

Comment: what is the `background-image: url(images/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png);` for? the `class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"` takes care of that.

Comment: add `class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"` to the button http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/wmu56vr9/

Comment: although it looks a bit awkward

Answer (score 0):

Try `visibility: hidden;` instead of `display: none;`

This will leave the button in the DOM but not show it to the user.

To add it back, use `visibility: visible;`

Hope this is helpful!